# Can yubikeys prevent cookie stealing?

Tags: passwords, cookies, yubikey, fido

When you log into a website, it stores cookies that let your browser access the website without having the password.

Given that some sites support yubikey for login, does it mean that the yubikey actively signs requests from my computer, or it just does a login and stores cookies?

In the first option, it would be better because stealing cookies would be innefective as only my computer would continuely be able to talk with the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't prevent cookie stealing.

Yubikeys (and other 2FA schemes) can protect you against password leaks and phishing. Some variants, such as U2F will entirely make phishing impossible, while others will narrow the time window and success rate significantly.

When it comes to cookie stealing, they do nothing. After you've authenticated and been given a token (often in form of a cookie), the 2FA does not enter again; you use the token for proving your identity.